# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role_not' ERROR

Tags: php, laravel, scope, user-roles

I am trying to display users other than super_admin so I used whereRoleNot Function in my controller to hide super_admin .
 My User Model:

```
public function scopeWhereRole($query, $role_name){
    return $query->whereHas('roles', function($q) use($role_name){
        return $q->whereIn('name', (array)'$role_name');
    });
}  //end of scopeWhereRole


public function scopeWhereRoleNotIn($query, $role_name){
    return $query->whereHas('roles', function($q) use($role_name){
        return $q->whereNotIn('name', (array)'$role_name');
    });
}  //scopeWhereRoleNotIn end
```

And User controller index method:

```
public function index()
 {
     //

     $users= User::whereRoleNot('super_admin')->paginate(3);
     return view('dashboard.users.index', compact('users'));
 }  //end of index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core issue is that you had a typo when using your scope, but due to the way you named your scope, it was still a valid `where{column}` clause.

Laravel has dynamic functions, like `where{column}($search)` that constructs a simple `where` clause for the `{column}` value and `$search` value provided. Take your example:

```
$users = User::whereRoleNot('super-admin');
```

`whereRoleNot` tries to create a `where` clause for the column, in your case, `role_not` (dynamically constructed from the string `RoleNot`), and your database table does not have this column.

Simply use a normal where clause:

```
$users = User::where('role', '!=', 'super_admin')->paginate(3);
```

Edit: If you want to use a scope, I'd suggest you change the name a bit:

```
public function scopeRoleIn($query, $role_name){
  return $query->whereHas('roles', function($q) use($role_name){
    return $q->whereIn('name', (array)$role_name); // Don't use `'` here
  });
} 

public function scopeRoleNotIn($query, $role_name){ 
  return $query->whereHas('roles', function($q) use($role_name){
    return $q->whereNotIn('name', (array)$role_name); // Don't use `'` here
  });
}
```

Then, use your scope as follows:

```
// $users = User::roleIn('super-admin')->paginate(3); // Etc...
$users = User::roleNotIn('super-admin')->paginate(3);
```

You may use `scopeWhere...`, but that naming potentially conflicts with Laravel's dynamic `where{column}` clauses, so you should avoid it.

Comment: No this is not true, even if where is a reserved keyword but still it will works. He just missed to call the exact name of local scope that why the error keeps showing.

Comment: I'm not sure which will take precedence, but you can do `where{column}`, so you should avoid naming a `scope` that will conflict with that. You're right that `whereRoleNot` doesn't match `scopeWhereRoleNotIn`, but I'm explaining why they were getting the error they were, and not an error regarding the wrong scope name. I also provided an approach to name and use scopes properly, to avoid this issue altogether, but apparently you still feel the need to downvote this?

Comment: probably!, cause you're not solving his problem with in his own way and your solution is even far with why the error is like that. Read again your code above if you truly hit the problem he is facing.

Comment: You need to understand why they're getting the error... Laravel's dynamic where clauses, like `whereRoleNot` (which is a typo of the scope, yes, but **still a valid where clause**) is causing the error. My solution is to A) use a normal `where` clause, or B), if using a scope, name it in a way **that does not conflict with `where{colunn}`**. How is that not a solution?

Comment: That's still a solution but yet remain the problem why the error is like that. Even me, at first reading your post I was surprised that scope name he used was invalid yet I already used that here on mine. If someone is reading your post also they will expect also that they cant do that which is bad without knowing that it will still works but not a good practice.

Comment: In  short, your answer tell us that you cannot make a scope name that start with where ? right ?

Comment: In short maybe, but you should read the whole answer before making conclusions like that. It was clearly explaining why when using `whereRoleNot`, which is a typo, was generating that error, and that if you change the naming of the scope and call it properly, it'll fix and avoid that error. I've changed the wording now, please re-read.

Answer (score 0):

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'role_not'
>   ERROR

It's because Laravel is expecting that you have a column 'role_not' in your User table considering that your local scope was named `scopeWhereRoleNotIn`, remove the prefix scope and it's final name will become `WhereRoleNotIn` yet you are calling the scope name as `WhereRoleNot`. Now you know why column 'role_not' is the error because Laravel is expecting that you were not already using local scope.

Now, to call this local scope, your query should look like this

```
public function index()
{
     $users= User::whereRoleNotIn('super_admin')->paginate(3);
     return view('dashboard.users.index', compact('users'));
 }
```

> Even if 'where' is a reserved keyword it will still works

It's jut a matter of you missed to call the exact name of your local scope that is  why Laravel is treating it as an where clause for your query builder.

please read docs [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: why down voted ? I tried the code above here on my local and its working.